# Permission denied when generating a rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a VPS with ubuntu trying to get rails to generate a controller but I keep getting a weird permissions error listed below, and when I try to use "sudo rails generate" it says command can't be found, any ideas?

```
    /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /run/user/0/spring (Errno::EACCES)
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/env.rb:37:in `tmp_path'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/env.rb:54:in `pidfile_path'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/env.rb:69:in `server_running?'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/katgus/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/katgus/appname/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The command rails was installed with rbenv for your user on `/home/katgus/.rbenv`. When you run `"sudo rails generate"` you are not using your user environment. Then you have that error.

The best way is fix permission problem to your user can create dirs.